$f f'' \geq 2(f')^ 2 \implies f$ decreasing
I'm currently doing a project and trying to find the conditions a function needs to have for the problem to have nice properties.
The conditions so far are:

$f(x) > 0$, $\; \forall x \in \text{dom } f$
$f$ is strict convex
$f(x) f''(x) \geq 2(f'(x))^ 2, \; \; \forall x \in \text{dom } f$

This last condition appears to restrict $f$ to be decreasing, but I don't know how to prove this. Can anybody shed a light?
Thanks.

Note that also $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the conditions. Maybe you want strictly convex, or with the strict inequaility in the 3rd condition...

Yeah, it should have been 'strict convex'. I'll change my question. thanks for the heads up!

@Ѕᴀᴀᴅ I'll change the wording to be only decreasing.  Thanks!

Still for any $c\in\mathbb R$, the function $f(x)=\dfrac1{c-x}$ ($x\in(-\infty,c)$) satisfies all conditions, and changing to $ff''>2(f')^2$ won't mitigate the issue. What matters here is that $+\infty$ should be in $\overline{\operatorname{dom}f}$.

If the condition $f.f''\geq 2(f')^2$ holds for $f$ then it also holds for $-f$, so the only thing you can hope for is that  if $f$ satisfies the condition then it is monotonic.

@krm2233: You cannot replace $f$ by $-f$ because of the condition $f(x) > 0$.

@MartinR ah fair point. However, you can also replace $f$ by $g(x)= f(-x)$, and then $g'(x) = -f'(-x)$, while $g''(x)= f''(-x)$ so that $g(x)g''(x) = f(-x)f''(-x)$ while $(g'(x))^2 = (f'(-x))^2$, so that the inequality will hold for $g$ if it holds for $f$. Similarly, $g(x)>0$ if $f(x)>0$ and $g$ is strictly convex if $f$ is.

For a nonnegative function, $f(x) f''(x) \geq 2(f'(x))^ 2$ means that $1/f$ is concave. As @krm2233 said, these conditions are invariant under the substitution $f(x) \mapsto f(-x)$, so  in the general case one cannot conclude that $f$ is decreasing.

$f$ is strictly convex hence $f'(x)$ is strictly increasing. We need to show that it is always negative.
If for some $c\ge 0$ and $x_0$ we have $f'(x_0)\ge c$ then $f'(x)>c$ for all $x>x_0$. Since $f'$ is strictly increasing we can also assume that $c>0$ (otherwise take $x_0:=x_0+1$).
Let $g(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}$. Then
$$
g'(x)=\frac{f''f^2-f'\cdot2ff'}{f^4}=\frac{f''f-2f'^2}{f^3}\ge 0
$$
so that $g$ is increasing. Take $x\ge x_0$, then $f'(x)\ge c>0$. Let $a=g(x_0)>0$, then for all $x\ge x_0$ we have $g(x)\ge a$ i.e.,
$$
f'(x)\ge a f(x)^2,\quad x\ge x_0
$$
(note that $f$ is increasing in this domain too). Consequently,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac1{f(x)}+ax\right)=a- \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}\le 0
$$
that is, $\frac1{f(x)}+ax$ is decreasing for all $x>x_0$. This is impossible as $f\uparrow$ and hence eventually the change in $\frac1{f(x)}$ becomes very small, while $ax$ increases at a constant speed.
